# Laravel 8 webpage shows only with refresh

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Today I've face very weird problem. My Laravel 8 app works totally find on `localhost`. After I've uploaded the app, I always face 404 when enter a url but after using `ctrl+F5` the page working fine!

**example**:

-example.com and then enter I face 404

-use ctrl+F5 on that page it works fine

I've tried these but no luck:

```
    composer dump-autoload
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan key:generate
    php artisan optimize
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan view:clear
```

roote htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where you have uploaded?

Comment: I've uploaded my code to Cpanel

Comment: is it inside public_html folder?

Comment: Note that the laravel core files should be outside your public folder, and the "public" folder of Laravel should be the root for your domain. you can change the root for your domain in cpanel.

Comment: @ArifulIslam, yeah it is in public_html folder

Comment: @GertB. thanks for your comment, I've used htaccess to handle that

Comment: @Sarah I know, but the core files are still open with the .htaccess you posted

Comment: I think your project is inside public_html/public
That's why are not getting response in browser